# What's the role of Teachers tag?

Tags: discussion

Academia is a Question and Answer website for graduate students and faculty members. What's the role of the [teachers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teachers) tag in this website.

I read the questions tagged with teachers which where not very related. Also there is no excerpt or wiki provided for it.

Comment: I just proposed that 'teachers' be a synonym of 'teaching', those who have the necessary reputation should feel free to [vote on this proposal](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)

Answer (score 2):

Academia is **not** a question and answer website for graduate students and faculty members. It is a website for people interested in asking questions about the "meta" aspects of research, teaching, and academic life in general. Its reach is much broader than just "graduate students and faculty members." Your definition, for instance, leaves out postdocs, and researchers at non-academic institutions.

That said, [teachers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teachers) can refer to anyone who is actively engaged in the teaching process: this can include graduate students, postdocs, professors, lecturers, visiting scientists, and even undergraduates acting as teaching assistants.